# Show label only every x number of steps in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have [this HighCharts chart](http://jsfiddle.net/bBahp/1/) that has more than 50 values on the x-asis. That's way to many, and I'd like to only show a value every x-number of steps. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change following bit of code by adding `minTickInterval`

```
xAxis: {
    categories: myArray,
    minTickInterval: 5                        
},
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBahp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

xAxis: {
    categories: myArray,
    tickInterval: 5
}

minTickInterval will only prevent showing smaller units if you zoom too much